# How to set up a development stage and a production stage in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am building the backend of my app on AWS CDK serverless. I'm not whats the best practice on setting up a development environment easily and the correct way. Meaning I want a totally separate infra code from my production to run test on, and once i'm sure push the code to the production infra obviously. Do I have to create two separate projects ? Whats the correct way of handling this?

would the right way possibly be to add the environment name to all the resources ? like so

Example:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3';

export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: { envConfig: any }) {
    super(scope, id);

    const { envConfig } = props;

    // Use envConfig to customize your resources based on the environment
    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyBucket' + envConfig.envName, {
      bucketName: envConfig.bucketName,
      versioned: envConfig.versioning,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });
  }
}
```

I have asked chat GPT but Im not sure about the answer

Based on your requirement to have a staging deployment stage and a production deployment stage, you can achieve this using AWS CDK by creating separate environments for staging and production, and using environment-specific Lambda functions and API Gateway configurations.

Here's an example of how you can modify the CDK stack to achieve this:

Create separate Lambda functions for the staging and production environments.

```js
const stagingLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'staging_lambda', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'staging.handler',
});

const productionLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'production_lambda', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'production.handler',
});
Create a separate API Gateway for each environment and integrate them with the respective Lambda functions.
const stagingApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'staging_api', { deploy: false });
const stagingIntegration = new apigw.LambdaIntegration(stagingLambda);
stagingApi.root.addMethod('ANY', stagingIntegration);

const productionApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'production_api', { deploy: false });
const productionIntegration = new apigw.LambdaIntegration(productionLambda);
productionApi.root.addMethod('ANY', productionIntegration);
Create separate deployments for each environment.
const stagingDeployment = new apigw.Deployment(this, 'staging_deployment', { api: stagingApi });
const productionDeployment = new apigw.Deployment(this, 'production_deployment', { api: productionApi });
Create separate API Gateway stages for each environment and associate them with the respective deployments.
```

Comment: Have two different AWS accounts and let CDK know nothing about it. Just use different credentials for your dev vs. prod deployment.

Comment: you have seriously tried this? Seems too simple/ anti-pattern-y to be true, excuse my hesitancy

Comment: That is ***the*** pattern to use, yes.

Comment: @luk2302 okay my question then is, what about names of things, for example a bucket must have a unique name, so do I feed different names based on environment for things that must be unique I assume ? Like so: 

```
    const { envConfig } = props;
    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyBucket' + envConfig.envName, {
```

Comment: Buckets are basically the only thing that needs to be globally unique. There you could depend on an environment config or you could let CDK generate the name entirely or you could include e.g. the account id in the bucket name, all valid, all have pros and cons.

Comment: beautiful thank you, in this case would you still need different stages in gateways ?

Comment: No need. I think there are very few actual users of multiple stages in API gateway, precisely because it runs exactly contrary to separating your environments which is **very important** from a security perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Having different aws accounts is the usual way to go for that because to can run your workloads on isolated environments. It means you provision an AWS account for production and other stages like Q&A.

You can read in detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/basic-organization.html).

You can still use AWS API Gateway to deploy multiple stages but this is commonly used to support multiple deployed versions of your api rather than providing development or testing areas.